# PHP Mysql Sub Menu array

Tags: php, mysql, css, submenu

Can you help in the making 
Drop Down Menu (submenu) With The Mycode Cat.php
FILE Include In Header
               Menu

```
/////// ( Home )//////////
include_once("./includes/config.php") ;

$mysqlQuery=new mysqlQueryClass();

$query="SELECT `catagory_id`, `name` FROM `catagories` WHERE `level` = 1";
$mysqlQuery->mysqlQueryWOF($query);

while (list($catagory_id,$name) = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQuery->result)) 
{                   
    $cats .= "<b>::</b> <a href='cat-$catagory_id,start-0'>$name</a><br>";
}



///(SubMenu level 2 About From Home)//////
$mysqlQuery=new mysqlQueryClass();

$query="SELECT `catagory_id`, `name` FROM `catagories` WHERE `level` = 2";
$mysqlQuery->mysqlQueryWOF($query);

while (list($catagory_id,$name) = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQuery->result)) 
{
    $cats .= "<b>::</b> <a href='cat-$catagory_id,start-0'>$name</a><br>";   
}
```

Pictures:http://s12.postimg.org/v2yxhk8gt/2016_01_17_06_21_08.png Level 1 = Menu Level2 = SubMenu

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what exactly you want.

Comment: Thanks @Matt I want to create sub Menu From  One Code Two To SubMenu Code

Comment: I have modified the code In top

Comment: @Matt Pictures:http://s12.postimg.org/v2yxhk8gt/2016_01_17_06_21_08.png Level 1 = Menu Level2 = SubMenu

Comment: can you correct your formatting? things like `One Menu` is obvious not part of the code

Comment: @Fabricator Thanks done edit questions Can You Help Me ?

Comment: Run only one query and than make associative array

Comment: Thanks @devpro How to do it :) ?

Comment: Or add $categoryid in second query where clause

Comment: Thanks @devpro Can you send me an example please have completely failed :(

Comment: Shared in answer hope this will work if not let me knw

Comment: @devpro Very Thanks To follow result  Error One Just :( Cat Home <b>::</b> <a href='cat-1,start-0'>Home</a><br>

Comment: @devpro picture : http://s17.postimg.org/liqbx2fv3/2016_01_17_07_08_32.png

Comment: @Fabricator Thanks for the reply sir The result error : Column 'level' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Not getting yur point what is the error did u try second answr?

Comment: @devpro Thanks result your code  <b>::</b> <a href='cat-1,start-0'>Home</a><br>   second answr = Column 'level' in where clause is ambiguous  :( :)

Comment: my bad, see the updated answer

Comment: Answer updated .. chk

Comment: Thanks Mr @devpro Now Work But <b>::</b> <a href='cat-1,start-0'>Home</a><br><b>::</b> <a href='cat-3,start-0'>index</a><br>  The result should be     // /// //     <b>::</b> <a href='cat-1,start-0'>Home</a><br><b>::</b> <a href='cat-3,start-0'>index</a><br><p><b>::</b> <a href='cat-1,start-0'>Catagories</a><br><b>::</b> <a href='cat-3,start-0'>Video</a></p>

Comment: @devpro Only one section showing the other does not

Comment: @devpro Thanks   echo"$catagory_id"; //result = 1  Only ? Thank you very much my teacher

Comment: @devpro  To solve this problem
Repeat // while (list($catagory_id,$name) = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQuery->result)) 
How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysqlQuery=new mysqlQueryClass();

$query="SELECT a.`catagory_id` parent_cat_id, a.`name` parent_cat, b.category_id, b.name 
  FROM `catagories` a
  LEFT JOIN `catagories` b on b.level = 2 and a.category_id = b.category
  WHERE a.`level` = 1";

$mysqlQuery->mysqlQueryWOF($query);
$id2name = array();
$cat_tree = array();

while (list($parent_id,$parent,$cat_id,$cat) = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQuery->result)) {
  $id2name[$parent_id] = $parent;
  $id2name[$cat_id] = $cat;
  $cat_tree[$parent_id][] = $cat_id;
}

foreach ($cat_tree as $parent_id => $child_ids) {
  $name = $id2name[$parent_id];
  $cats .= "<b>::</b> <a href='cat-$parent_id,start-0'>$name</a><br>";

  foreach ($child_ids as $id) {
    if (is_null($id)) continue;
    $child = $id2name[$id];
    $cats .= "<b>::::</b> <a href='cat-$id,start-0'>$child</a><br>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create menu and sub menu as like:

```
$mysqlQuery=new mysqlQueryClass();
$query="SELECT `catagory_id`, `name` FROM `catagories` WHERE `level` = 1";
$mysqlQuery->mysqlQueryWOF($query);


while (list($catagory_id,$name) = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQuery->result)) 
{                   
      $cats .= "<b>::</b> <a href='cat-$catagory_id,start-0'>$name</a><br>";   

    $query="SELECT `catagory_id`, `name` FROM `catagories` WHERE `level` = 2 AND main_category = ". $catagory_id ;
     $mysqlQuery->mysqlQueryWOF($query);
        while (list($scatagory_id,$sname) = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQuery->result)) 
       {                   
      $cats .= "<b>::</b> <a href='cat-$scatagory_id,start-0'>$sname</a><br>";   

      }
}
```